# Distribution of stochastic integral w.r.t. to centered Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $N(t)$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ and define the centered process as $N_0(t):= N(t)-\lambda t$. A stochastic integral can be properly defined w.r.t. to $N_0(t)$ (but not w.r.t. $N(t)$).

Let $f$ be a nice function, for concreteness let's say $f(s)=s^2$. I want to calculate the distribution (also covariances in the time domain) of the process

$$X(t) := \int_0^t s^2 \;dN_0(s)$$

I have tried the following argument:

Consider the partial sums

$$S_n = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} t_i^2 \;(N_0(t_{i+1}) - N_0(t_i)),$$

where $0=t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n=t$ is some partition of the interval $[0,t]$.

Then $\mathbb E[S_n] = 0$ and $Var[S_n] = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} t_i^4 \lambda (t_{i+1} - t_i)$, using the independence of increments of the process $N_0(t)$.

Now, in analogy to the argument for an integral w.r.t. to Brownian motion being again normal, I tried to calculate the characteristic function of the distribution of $S_n$ hoping that by taking its limit I would get something I can interpret. Using the fact that the sum of two independent Poisson distributions (fulfilled by independence of increments) is again Poisson, I am left with the problem that I don't know how to deal with the prefactor $t_i^2$, since the distribution of $t_i^2 (N_0(t_{i+1}) - N_0(t_i))$ is nothing really nice, as far as I can tell.

**Questions**:

Can one properly finish my argument or is there a nicer way to calculate the above stochastic integral within $L^2$-theory without referring to Ito calculus?

What can one say about $CoV(X(t),X(s))$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stochastic integrals which interest you can be properly defined with respect to $N=(N(t))_{t\geqslant0}$ as well, for example, for every deterministic function $u$,
$$
X(t)=\int_0^tu(s)\mathrm dN(s)=\sum_{k=1}^{N(t)}u(T_k),
$$
where $(T_k)_{k\geqslant1}$ enumerates the jump times of the process $N$. Conditioning on $N(t)=n$, $\{T_k\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n\}$ is distributed like $\{U_k\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n\}$ where $(U_k)_k$ is an i.i.d. sample uniformly distributed on $(0,t)$. Thus,
$$
E[X(t)\mid N(t)]=N(t)\int_0^tu(s)\frac{\mathrm ds}t,
$$
and
$$
E[X(t)]=E[N(t)]\int_0^tu(s)\frac{\mathrm ds}t=\lambda\int_0^tu(s)\mathrm ds.
$$
More generally, for every $a$,
$$
E[\mathrm e^{aX(t)}\mid N(t)]=\left(\int_0^t\mathrm e^{au(s)}\frac{\mathrm ds}t\right)^{N(t)},
$$
hence
$$
E[\mathrm e^{aX(t)}]=\exp\left(\lambda\int_0^t(\mathrm e^{au(s)}-1)\mathrm ds\right).
$$
This, together with the fact that the increments of $X=(X(t))_t$ are independent, fully determines the joint distribution of the process $X$. Now,
$$
X_0(t)=\int_0^tu(s)\mathrm dN_0(s)
$$
is simply
$$
X_0(t)=X(t)-\lambda\int_0^tu(s)\mathrm ds,
$$
hence  the joint distribution of the process $X_0=(X_0(t))_t$ is fully determined by the fact that its increments are independent and by the identity
$$
E[\mathrm e^{aX_0(t)}]=\exp\left(\lambda\int_0^t(\mathrm e^{au(s)}-1-au(s))\mathrm ds\right).
$$
For example, for every $0\leqslant s\leqslant t$, 
$$
\mathrm{cov}(X_0(s),X_0(t))=\mathrm{var}(X_0(s))=E[X_0(s)^2]=\lambda\int_0^su(x)^2\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Could tell me, why in the last line the covariance at two different times is the same as the variance at the earlier time?

Comment: Because the increments are independent.

Comment: how would this change for a non-homogenous poisson process? especially this part: "where $(U_k)_k$ is an i.i.d. sample uniformly distributed on..."

Comment: @MichaelMark This part would not hold in the wider context you suggest. By the way, if you have new questions, the modus operandi is not to post comments on answers to old questions but to ask them as separate posts.